# Data entry for SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database

I am looking for suggestions on a simple solution to build data entry forms that will save manually input records into a SQL Server database. Microsoft InfoPath is capable of this, but it has been deprecated in 2017.

What alternatives can I consider?

Answer (score 0):

build a html/php web form.... That's a simple solution